# How to add ODBC System DSN for Access Database?

Tags: vb.net, odbc, dsn

I tried My best to add ODBC System Data Source for Access (.accdb) Database using VB.NET. Searching from Google I tried many Functions but nothing worked.

Code I tried is :

```
Sub createDSN()

    Const ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4 ' Add data source
    Dim dbpath As String = "C:\Jenit\Data\001.accdb"

    Dim ret As Integer, Driver As String, Attributes As String

    Driver = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.MDB,*.accdb)" & Chr(0)
    Attributes = "DSN=" & "Hello" & Chr(0)
    Attributes = Attributes & "Uid=Admin" & Chr(0) & "pwd=pwd" & Chr(0)
    Attributes = Attributes & "DBQ=" & dbpath & Chr(0) & Chr(0)

    ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0&, ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, Driver, Attributes) 'Error Here


    'ret is equal to 1 on success and 0 if there is an error
    If ret <> 1 Then
        MsgBox("DSN Creation Failed")
    Else
        MsgBox("Successful")
    End If
End Sub 'Main
```

Error is :

*A call to PInvoke function 'j!j.Form1::SQLConfigDataSource' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.*

Please Help.

Comment: Please show your DLLImport portion of your code.  Most likely you need to pass in an `Int32` (`Integer`) for the handle (the first argument of the function), not an `Int64` (`Long`) value.  Check this page for more information (scroll to bottom for VB.NET code): http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your `<DllImport>` statement, it's difficult to give you an exact answer, but I'm making an educated guess (based on [sqlconfigdatasource (odbccp32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbccp32.sqlconfigdatasource) at pinvoke.net) and the code you provided that you've defined your `SQLConfigDataSource` function as something like this:

```
Public Shared Function SQLConfigDataSourceW(ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal fRequest As Integer, ByVal lpszDriver As String, ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Integer
```

When in reality `hwndParent` is an 32-bit integer (`Integer` in VB.NET), so it should look something like this:

```
Public Shared Function SQLConfigDataSourceW(ByVal hwndParent As Integer, ByVal fRequest As Integer, ByVal lpszDriver As String, ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Integer
```

The you would call it like this:

```
ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0, ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, Driver, Attributes)
```

Note `0` is an `Integer`, whereas `0&` is a `Long`.

**EDIT**
From pinvoke.net:

```
<DllImport("ODBCCP32.dll",CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.WinAPI,CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode,SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function SQLConfigDataSourceW(ByVal hwndParent As Integer, ByVal fRequest As Integer, ByVal lpszDriver As String, ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Integer
```

Then simply replace your current line

```
ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0&, ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, Driver, Attributes)
```

With this:

```
ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0, ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, Driver, Attributes)
```

Comment: Can you please give me a working code snippet? It would be more useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Jenit - Without more information (specifically, your current code for the DllImport) it's hard to give you anything more than I already did.  I added what the DllImport should like from the link I gave you to pinvoke.net; if you need more information can you post all of your relevant code in your question?